# Interesting questions about Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The following is my Makefile:

```
CC=mpicc
CFLAGS=-Wall -O3
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OUTS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
SRC_CODE=\
        mpiex1.c\
        mpiex2.c\
        mpiex3.c
SOFI2D_OBJ=$(SRC_CODE:%.c=%.o)
sofi2D: $(SOFI2D_OBJ)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
clean:
        rm -rf *.o *.o* *~ *.dSYM $(OUTS)   
all: clean sofi2D
```

Three questions:

(1) I don't think

```
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

is necessary here, because .o files are intermediate ones, I can delete this command and write a simpler one like:

```
CC=mpicc
CFLAGS=-Wall -O3
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OUTS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))
SRC_CODE=\
        mpiex1.c\
        mpiex2.c\
        mpiex3.c
sofi2D: $(SRC_CODE)
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
clean:
        rm -rf *.o *.o* *~ *.dSYM $(OUTS)   
all: clean sofi2D
```

Am I right? So at this time I'll only get executable files without generation of any obj files?

(2) If the 3 source codes are irrelevant to each other, how can I compile them one by one? I tried the following, am I right?

```
CC=mpicc
CFLAGS=-Wall -O3
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OUTS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))
SRC_CODE=\
        mpiex1.c\
        mpiex2.c\
        mpiex3.c
all: $(SRC_CODE)
%: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean:
        rm -rf *.o *.o* *~ *.dSYM $(OUTS)   
.PHONY: clean
```

In this way it seems that no obj files will be generated (I can only get executable files). So how to modify the above so that I can get both obj and exe files?

(3) What does $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS)) mean, how to read this piece in English?

Comment: hi! You've got a miserable title. Please describe the subject in the title, not whether you find it interesting. Thanks!

Comment: 1 question per question, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), if you write this:

```
sofi2D: $(SRC_CODE)
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

then yes, it won't create intermediate object files.  But on the other hand, every time you change any single file *all* the files will have to be recompiled completely.  The goal of using object files is to avoid recompiling the world when anything changes.  If you want to do this you really don't even need a makefile, you can just use a shell script that compiles everything.

For (2) I don't understand what you want.  When you say "the source codes are irrelevant to each other" what do you mean?  You  mean, you want to compile three different executables, one from each source file?  If you want to do that you can use the rule you created but you have to remove the `-c` flag: that flag tells the compiler to not build an executable but just build an object file (see your compiler's documentation).

If you mean you want to compile object files, then you already had that in your original makefile.

If you don't mean those things, please explain more clearly.

For (3) you can look in the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) for a full description but in short that means "remove `.c` from the end of every word in the expansion of the `$(SRCS)` macro".

Comment: Thank you. For the first question, when I use sofi2D: $(SRC_CODE)
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ , it only generates .o files instead of executable "sofi2D" file, and a warning also pops up saying "multiple sources not allowed with -o option". So why?

Comment: As I mentioned above, you can't use `-c` with your compiler if you want to create an executable.  That flag tells the compiler to create object files and stop.